# Can different CPUs on an x86 machine can have different local APIC register MMIO base addresses?

Tags: x86, intel, interrupt, pci

Intel manual says that local APIC registers are memory mapped to a 4KB region, with the default address being **FEE00000H**. This address can be modified using **IA32_APIC_BASE** MSR.

Quoting SDM Vol 3, section 10.4.5

> The Pentium 4, Intel Xeon, and P6 family processors permit
>    the starting address of the APIC registers to be relocated from FEE00000H to another physical address by modifying the value in the 24-bit base address field of the 
>   IA32_APIC_BASE MSR. This extension of the APIC architecture is provided to help resolve conflicts with memory
>   maps of existing systems and to allow individual processors in an MP system to map their APIC registers to different locations in physical memory.

1. Is it possible that different CPUs, on the same machine at the same time, can have different base addresses for local APIC ? Say, CPU 0 decides to stay at FEE00000H, but CPU1 move to FEF00000H
2. If above is true, how can PCI MSI interrupts work ? If different CPUs can have different local APIC addresses, then MSI message address means different for different CPUs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, as you quoted this is explicitly allowed by the Intel's manuals. 
   However, since the P6 architecture the APIC accesses are handled internally by the processor, with no visible external bus cycle.

   > For P6 family, Pentium 4, and Intel Xeon processors, the APIC handles all memory accesses to
   >   addresses within the 4-KByte APIC register space internally and no external bus cycles are
   >   produced.

   So the remapping is done only to avoid conflicts with legacy devices.
   Today, this is a rare circumstance since the region from 4 GiB - 18 MiB to 4GiB - 17 MiB (open-ended) is reserved for the MSI.
2. From the PCI point-of-view, MSIs are extremely simple: write a value to an address.
   Both the address and the value are configured in the PCI address space of the device through the [*MSI* or *MSI-x* capability structures](https://pcisig.com/sites/default/files/specification_documents/msi-x_ecn.pdf) (values 05h and 11h respectively).
   Only the *MSI-x* allows for 32-bit of data.

   The PCI specs are intentionally generic, the address and data pair form a unique "interrupt vector", i.e. a value that identifies an interrupt.
   First devices actually have a very limited extension of the `MESSAGE_DATA` field with only a few lower bits writable.
   In the x86 architecture, however, the address and data take a specific form.
   These are described in the section 10.11 of the Intel's manual 3A.

   ```
   Address format

   31   20  19            12  11         4   3    2  0
   0FEEH    Destination ID    Reserved   RH  DM   XX

   Data format

   63     16   15   14   13     11  10          8  7   0
   Reserved    TM   LM   Reserved   Delivery mode  Vector
   ```

   We can see that these formats are compatible with both MSI and MSI-x but more importantly that the address has a prefix of 0feeh making it at least 0fee00000h i.e.
   4 GiB - 18 MiB.
   This area is used to route MSIs by the Host-to-PCI i.e. the Root Complex (either on the CPU chip or in the PCH) or the MCH (for older platforms).
   The address determines which set of processors will handle the MSI (the exact rules can be found in the Intel's manual).

   **Even if all local APICs are mapped at the same address, it is the format of the destination address that selects a set of processors**, the design of the x86's MSI is to allow the OS to direct interrupts to specific processors.
   So, no, the MSI address means the same thing for every CPU because it's not the CPU that handles the PCI write but the Host-to-PCI bridge and this chip is system-wide.

---

How can the Host-to-PCI know where to send the MSI?

The address has a destination ID (MDA in intel terms - Message Destination Address) that, along with some meta information, is enough to route the message in the "APIC bus" - a logical structure, implementation defined (probably the ring bus with some QPI/UPI/DMI segment), that connects the APICs and the clusters of APICs.
Pretty much very similar to how network packets are routed.

Don't the MSIs range and the default local APIC range overlap?

Yes, but these ranges lives in two different "address space": the local APIC range lives inside each core or at most in the uncore (but not in the System Agent) the MSIs ranges lives in the Host-to-PCI chip.
Writes from the PCI bus targeted to the MSIs range never leaves the Host-to-PCI bridge while accesses to the local APIC range never leave the cores.
The communication between these two domains is through the APIC bus.

---

## Addendum

A question arose in the comments: In an system with [VT-d](http://lettieri.iet.unipi.it/virtualization/vt-directed-io-spec.pdf) enabled (essentially a IOMMU), why there is the need for an Interrupt Remapping (IR) machinery? Why can't the DMA remapping suffice?

Since MSI(-X) are memory writes initiated from a device the DMA remapping should be enough to remap interrupts.

The DMA remapping translates *addresses* while a MSI(-X) is made of a target address (that conveys the destination of the interrupt) and a data (that specifies the type of interrupt to deliver).
To allow the software to fully control the interrupt to be delivered the VT-d specification introduced a new format for the MSI(-X): *the remappable format*.
The idea is similar to the standard memory translation used by the CPU: the MSI(-X) just have the necessary info to index a table with the full definition of the interrupt's target and type.

The new format is:

[image: Remappable MSI(-X) format]

There are essentially three fields:

- The `Handle` and `Sub handle` fields
  They are **added** together to get the index into the IR Table (IRT). They have been separated because the `Sub handle` is in the *Data* register (while the `Handle` is in the address register), this allows for configuring a device with a single address and multiple data values (apparently this turned out to be a necessary requirement).
- The `SHV` field to tell if the `Sub handle` field is valid, otherwise zero is used instead.

Note that the index is a 16-bit value.

Once the index has been found, it is used to retrieve the IRT entry (IRTE) that contains all the information to deliver the interrupt -  including some field to validate the source of the interrupt.

Note that the legacy (Compatible format) MSI(-X) are *never* remapped, either they pass-through or they are blocked (depending on how the software configure the translator).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Few followup questions

1. Does that mean that each CPU has its own IA32_APIC_BASE MSR ? In other words, is that register banked (like the APIC registers itself) ?

2. Referring to prl's answer above, is it true that there is no relation between the APIC address and MSI target address ? Even if CPU changes APIC base address,  does the MSI target still remains FEExxxx ?

Comment: 3. In a hypothetical scenario in which another MMIO device is mapped to FEExxx region, does that stop a PCI device from writing to that device - because all PCI writes to that region by the device will turn out as an interrupt message instead ? I mean CPU can access that region by remapping APIC base, but the PCI device possibly couldn't  ?

Comment: @joz 1. Yes, `IA32_APIC_BASE_MSR` is per hw thread. 2. Yes, maybe it's not well worded but in my answer I explicitly say that the MSI address is not related to the local APIC address. 3. To my understanding, yes. Though the write is visible on the PCI bus so a device mapped there may still respond to it and interfere. I'd say that no PCI device *should* access the region.

Comment: Thanks.  _this is a rare circumstance since the region from 4 GiB - 18 MiB to 4GiB (open-ended) is reserved for the MSI._  Since the address has to start on 0FEE, shouldn't the reserved space be just 1 MB instead of the entire 18 MB ?

Comment: @joz, Absolutely! You are right, I thought the whole range was reserved but a fixed prefix fixes the size to 1 MiB.

Comment: One more query, What is the need for interrupt remapping in virtualized environment  since MSI writes are just DMA writes to a special address ? Shouldn't DMA remapping hardware intercepts those 'special' writes (MSI writes). Is it because PCI host bridge intercepts those messages even before it reaches IOMMU ?

Comment: @joz Interrupt remapping as used in VT-d? that's a security and control feature (so different OSes don't interfere with each other receiving each others interrupts). It's implemented in the PCI host bridge. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/745593/does-disabling-vt-d-and-interrupt-remapping-break-msi-x). I need to read that document for a better reply. After lunch :)

Comment: Yes, VT-d - DMA remapping and interrupt remapping. I realize that it is a security feature designed to confine interrupts from devices assigned to VMs from raising malicious interrupts. Where I am confused is couldn't the DMA remapping hardware do the same job ? Because, after all MSI messages are essentially PCI writes to a special address. So DMA remapping hw can look at the Destination address of the PCI write transaction, perhaps ?

Comment: @joz, the remapping logic is more involved. The document linked in that answer (google its name, the link seems broken) describes the whole story. Anyway, quoting the VT-d spec: "Since interrupt requests arrive at the Root-Complex as write requests,
interrupt-remapping is co-located with the remapping hardware units." So interrupt remapping uses the DMA remapping but with additional logic on top. For example, a new format of MSI is added. Let me see if I can put something together in my answer

Comment: Thanks. I was going through qemu/vfio mailing lists which deals with the same and it turns out that it is complex. I thought interrupt-remapping was relatively straight forward like DMA remapping. Quoting one of the comments, _On a standard PC, Message Signaled Interrupts (MSI) are triggered via a DMA write by the device to a special address range.  In the early revisions of VT-d, the IOMMU did not protect this range, which allowed devices to effectively spoof interrupts from other devices and potentially run attacks against the host using DMA writes to this interrupt block_

Comment: @joz, edited. It's a short summary but should suffice to understand why IR is needed in addition to DMA remapping.

Comment: With this, do you think a VM can configure interrupts for its own devices ? I mean, with this format, it still looks like MSI(x) table should not be accessed by VM directly. If allowed, how does the handle number configured by a VM makes sense to the hypervisor ?

Comment: @joz It's the VMM that handles the MSIs. The IR is mostly a security feature, they should have called it Interrupt Filtering. It disallows a rouge device from attacking a CPU with the special interrupts (like SIPI) that executes at a designed location. However it doesn't allow a guest to directly control a device, the VMM still intercept the attempt to write to the PCI config space. IR offers some benefits for the VMM, like the possibility of migrating a VM without reconfiguring its devices. But it's mostly isolation. Interrupt Posting can be used to speed up virtualization.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can be different.

The MSI address, even though it is the same as the default APIC address, is not tied to it. The MSI address doesn’t change if the APIC base address is changed.